# Can't view SSL certificate with chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, certificate

When I try to view a certificate, a dialog popup and I'm unable to see the contents.

What could the problems be?

[image]

Comment: what is your chrome version?

Comment: @FrontENG Version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit)

Comment: blank popup happens on every website?

Comment: @FrontENG I don't think it's blank. I guess the dialog is too big, i.e I didn't see the window title